# The functional $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p dx$ is invariant under dialation and translation in $\mathbb{R}^N$. How?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

The functional $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p dx$ is invariant under dialation and translation in $\mathbb{R}^N$. How?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that it is translation invariant since
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u(x+t)|^p dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u(x)|^p dx.
$$
You can see this by performing the change of variable $x \mapsto x+t$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}^N$.
However, it is in general not dilation invariant. Consider the dilation $x \mapsto \lambda x$ for some positive $\lambda$. Then we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla (u(\lambda x))|^p dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \lambda^p |\nabla u(\lambda x)|^p dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{\lambda^p}{\lambda^N} |\nabla u( x)|^p dx
$$
The last equality again follows by a change of variables. So the functional is dilation invariant iff $p=N$.